# Get-ADGroup pulling all groups but Domain Users

Tags: powershell, active-directory

For some reason this script works perfect except it does not pull the "Domain Users" group, does anybody know why or how to get it?  It pulls all other groups.

```psh
Import-Module Activedirectory
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | sort SamAccountName | % {
  New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    "First" = $_.givenName
    "Init" = If($_.Initials -eq $null){Write-Host ""} else {$_.Initials}
    "Last" = $_.SN
    "Enabled" = $_.Enabled
    "Logon Name" = $_.samaccountname
    "UserName" = $_.DisplayName
    "Pass Last Set" = If($_.PasswordLastSet -eq $null){Write-Host ""} else {$_.PasswordLastSet}
    "Pass Expiration" = If($_.PasswordLastSet -eq $null){Write-Host ""} else {$_.PasswordLastSet.AddDays(270)}
    "Pass Expired" = $_.PasswordExpired
    "Days Til Exp" = If($_.PasswordLastSet -eq $null){Write-Host ""} else {($_.PasswordLastSet.AddDays(270) - [DateTime]::Now)}
    "Pass Never Expires" = $_.PasswordNeverExpires
    "Account Created" = $_.whenCreated
    "Last Logon" = $_.LastLogonDate
    "Email Address" = $_.EmailAddress

    Groups = ($_.memberof | Get-ADGroup | Select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName) -join ", "
    }
} | Select "Logon Name",First,Init,Last,Enabled,"Pass Last Set","Pass Expiration","Pass Expired","Days Til Exp","Pass Never Expires","Last Logon","Email Address",Groups
```

I noticed it doesn't pull Domain Users even with the Quest Snapin

```psh
Add-PSSnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement

$strUserName = "username"
$strUser = get-qaduser -SamAccountName $strUserName
$strUser.memberof
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't see it because "Domain Users", for *most* users, is [the Primary Group](https://serverfault.com/questions/518608/purpose-of-primary-group). In AD Users and Computers they appear in the same list but they are the combination of attributes.

With the AD cmdlets you will find it using the `PrimaryGroup` property of Get-AdUser for example.

```
PS C:\Users\matt> Get-ADUser matt -Properties PrimaryGroup | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PrimaryGroup
CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=BA,DC=NET
```

More in line with what you are doing is using the [`Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ee617259.aspx) cmdlet.

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership matt

distinguishedName : CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=DOMAIN,DC=NET
GroupCategory     : Security
GroupScope        : Global
name              : Domain Users
objectClass       : group
objectGUID        : d2745cb0-7f6d-4ada-a44c-0926a0950a74
SamAccountName    : Domain Users
SID               : S-1-5-21-961215277-3068250917-3774519051-513
```